# Redis Cluster: (error) MOVED

Tags: configuration, cluster, redis

I have a Redis cluster with the following nodes:

```
192.168.0.14:6379 master (slots from 0 to 16383)
192.168.0.15:6379 slave (slots from 0 to 16383)
192.168.0.16:6379 master (without slots)
```

Documentation says that any node can redirect queries to the properly node. But I can not redirect requests from 192.168.0.16:6379 master node. Here is what I tried:

```
192.168.0.16:6379> set myKey myValue
(error) MOVED 16281 192.168.0.14:6379
192.168.0.16:6379> get myKey
(error) MOVED 16281 192.168.0.14:6379
```

It neither writes nor reads. When I try to get "myKey" from 192.168.0.14:6379 it shows next:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get myKey
(nil)
```

What is wrong with my requests? I am using redis server version 3.2.5

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The node *did* redirect you.

As the [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) explains, the client is expected to connect to the specified node to retry the request. The *server* does not do this.

If you're using `redis-cli`, then you must [use the `-c` option](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) if you want it to follow these redirects.

Answer (score 0):

For get commands you may want to run:

```
READONLY
```

first as one of the following [might have happened](https://redis.io/commands/readonly/):

> 1. The client sent a command about hash slots never served by the
>    master of this replica.
> 2. The cluster was reconfigured (for example resharded) and the replica
>    is no longer able to serve commands for a given hash slot.